# Map new user to table owner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a database that was accessed as user MARY on the old SQL Server. All the tables are:

```
MARY.<tablename>
```

The application assumes it can access tables by name only. E.g. `select * from <tablename>` rather than `select * from MARY.<tablename>`

We have a new userid that the software uses to access the database: `APPSERVER`.

When APPSERVER logs in, it has full rights to the DB, but can only access the tables as `MARY.<tablename>`.

So the code will not run.

How do I either:

- get new user APPSERVER to magically map to `MARY.` to access tables

  or
- update all tables so they are now: `APPSERVER.<tablename>`.

(This is all via SQL native auth, not integrated.)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adjusting the SQL user id to have the appropriate default schema... and tada!

Comment: You could also have created a synonym on the APPSERVER schema (or whatever its default schema is) to point to the MARY.object.

Comment: Or better yet, fix the app code to specify the right schema. Always better to be explicit than rely on opaque things like default schema. https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are completely correct. But this is a compiled java app that we do not have sources to.

Comment: @samsmith Java? Have you checked a calendar lately? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are completely correct RE java. Tell the folks at Atlassian that.